# How to use "this" in async function?

Tags: node.js

I have simple example:

```
function File(name) {
   this.name = name
   this.text = null
}

File.prototype = {
    read: function() {
         fs.readFile(this.name, function (err, data) {
     }
    },
    getContent: function() {
         return this.text
     }
}

var myfile = new File('my_file')

watch.createMonitor('my_file_dir', function (monitor) {
    monitor.files['my_file']
    monitor.on("change", function (f, stat) {
        myfile.read()
    }
})

  main program....:

   myfile.getContent() ...
```

I want to add file contents in this.text variable. How to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Create local variable and store there 'this'

  read: function() {
       var _file = this;
       fs.readFile(this.name, function (err, data) {
          ...
          _file.text = data;
          ...
       });
  },
- Bind 'this' to inner function:
  read: function() {

  ```
   fs.readFile(this.name, function (err, data) {
       ...
       this.text = data;
       ...
   }.bind(this)
  ```

  },

Note:
It's insufficiently to store data to this.text: if you read something asynchronously in yur class, you need to provide callbacks to let other objects know that you got some data in yourFile.text

Answer (score 4):

You could save a reference to `this` outside the closure and reference it from within:

```
File.prototype = {
    read: function() {
        var self = this;
        fs.readFile(this.name, function (err, data) {
            self.text = data;
        });
    },
    getContent: function() {
        return this.text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you can do:

1. Create a scoped version of `this`:

   ```
   File.prototype = {
     read: function() {
       var self = this;
       fs.readFile(this.name, function (err, data) {
         self.text += data;
       });
     }
   };
   ```
2. Bind the function to the current value of `this`:

   ```
   File.prototype = {
     read: function() {
       fs.readFile(this.name, function (err, data) {
         this.text += data;
       }.bind(this));
     }
   };
   ```